# why Gson is able to serialize/deserialize but jackson objectmapper is failing

Tags: java, api, jackson, gson, pojo

i have below Json string and i want to deserialize the same using some objectMapper tool like Jackson . But it is throwing Exception

> Unrecognized field "CPREQUESTS" (Class mmt.jacoco.Respon), not marked as ignorable

Have used many naming conventions in Pojo class  for naming datamembers. had used `@JsonProperty("CPREQUESTS")` too .  All i can get an idea is that i have to use some naming convention while serializing -deserializing the same but not able to solve the same .

That is working fine with Gson but jackon is failing

```
public class APItesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

          String res  = "{\r\n  \"CPREQUESTS\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"a\": \"b\"\r\n    },\r\n    "
                            + "{\r\n      \"a\": \"d\"\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"costAmount\": 10488\r\n}";

          Gson g = new Gson();
          Respon s = g.fromJson(res, Respon.class);
          System.out.println(s.getCPREQUESTS().get(0).getA());
          System.out.println(s.getCPREQUESTS().get(1).getA());
          System.out.println(s.getCostAmount());
          System.out.println(s.getCPREQUESTS().size());

          ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
          Respon s1 = om.readValue(res, Respon.class);
          System.out.println(s1.getCPREQUESTS().size());
    }
}
```

Respon.class is as below :-

```
public class Respon {


    private List<CPREQUESTS> CPREQUESTS = null;

    @JsonProperty("costAmount")
    private Integer costAmount;

    @JsonProperty("CPREQUESTS")
    public List<CPREQUESTS> getCPREQUESTS() {
        return CPREQUESTS;
    }

    @JsonProperty("CPREQUESTS")
    public void setCPREQUESTS(List<CPREQUESTS> cPREQUESTS) {
        this.CPREQUESTS = cPREQUESTS;
    }

    @JsonProperty("costAmount")
    public Integer getCostAmount() {
        return costAmount;
    }

    @JsonProperty("costAmount")
    public void setCostAmount(Integer costAmount) {
        this.costAmount = costAmount;
    }         
}
```

Comment: which jackson you are using, I tested and its working. It seems your project has both version of jackson. Ensure `JsonProperty` and `ObjectMapper` should be from same jackson lib, either from codehaus (jackson 1) or fasterxml (jackson 2)

Comment: With GSON it is working because gson uses reflection to fetch fields name, wheras jackson uses setter / getter (by default) for serialization / deserialization.

Comment: jackson (obviously) uses reflection as well

Comment: Thanks @HemantPatel for your help  .  My issue was that in one file i was using Jackson1 & in other was using jackson 2 imports which is causing the issue .

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project has two different versions of jackson. Ensure that your imports for `JsonProperty` and `ObjectMapper` are from same jackson lib, either from codehaus (jackson 1) or fasterxml (jackson 2)